# How to find occurrence of each set of cartesian product in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartesian-product, find-occurrences

I want to find occurrence of each set of Cartesian product like

```
A = [1,2]
B = [2,1]
```

then

```
A * B = [(1,2),(1,1),(2,2),(2,1)]
```

then I want to find occurrence of each set like
`(1,2)` occurs 2 times `[(1,2), (2,1)]`
`(1,1)` occurs 1 time `(1,1)`
and so on....

Comment: are you familiar with `itertools`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `itertools`'s `product` and `collections`'s `Counter`

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
A = [1,2]
B = [2,1]
li = list(product(A,B))
li_count =  Counter(tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in li)
```

---

**li:**

```
[(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1)]
```

**li_count:**

```
Counter({(1, 2): 2, (1, 1): 1, (2, 2): 1})
```